# Two versions of same function: inline and normal?

Tags: c

I'd like to inline some functions, however, they are shared across the team and I don't want to force people to use them.

What would be the best way to add inline versions?

```
// normal
int func1();
int func2();
// inline versions
inline int inl_func1() { ... }
inline int inl_func2() { ... }
```

Would something like that make sense?

**Edit**:
Ideally:

- I wouldn't have to write the same function definitions (function body) twice.
- It would all be handled with s single `define`.

Comment: Why do you want to inline them? I'd suggest reading http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/033.htm (I know it's a C++ blog, but I think the points are applicable).

Comment: I checked with `gprof` profiler, and I get significant speed increase, which is crucial (code is running on a DSP processor).

Comment: Well, if you've actually profiled and achieved actual performance improvement, that's reason enough for me.

Comment: @chux fixed it.

Comment: Funny thing, your compiler may decide to inline func1 and func2 anyway, if it feels like there would be a gain.  I'm surprised that it isn't doing so already if you are seeing this gain, unless no-inline is specified as a flag.  And if that is the case, it might be worth a test and team talk about possibly changing said compiler flag.

Comment: @chux Fixed naming.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could tell the people who want the inline functions to define a specific macro before including your header file:

```
#define WANT_INLINE_FUNC1
#include "awesome_funcs.h"
```

People who want the to call the externally linked function should omit the macro:

```
#include "awesome_funcs.h"
```

Then, in "awesome_funcs.h":

```
#ifdef WANT_INLINE_FUNC1
inline int func1(int param)
{
    /* function body here */
}
#else
extern int func1(int param);
#endif
```

You also need to define a copy of the function with external linkage in one of your library files, e.g. in "awesome_funcs.c":

```
#define WANT_INLINE_FUNC1
#include "awesome_funcs.h"

/*
 * This will define func1 with external linkage,
 * but the function body is copied from the inline definition
 * in "awesome_funcs.h".
 */
extern int func1(int param);
```

**EDIT 1**

You could combine this with chux's answer and get the best of both worlds (unless that makes things too confusing for your users).  Just replace `func1` in "awesome_funcs.h" with the following:

```
static inline int inl_func1(int param)
{
    /* function body here */
}

#ifdef WANT_INLINE_FUNC1
inline int func1(int param)
{
    return inl_func1(param);
}
#else
extern int func1(int param);
#endif
```

Then `inl_func1` will always be the inline version, and `func1` may or may not be inline, depending on whether or not the `WANT_INLINE_FUNC1` macro was defined before including "awesome_funcs.h".

Comment: I tried your first suggestion (and undefed `WANT_INLINE_FUNC1`), but it doesn't link: `undefined reference to func1`. Can you check your suggestion once more?

Comment: I don't get the part where you say "function body is copied from the inline definition in "awesome_funcs.h"". How is is copied from .h to .c?

Comment: @Danijel Perhaps it needs the `extern` keyword to force it to create the function with external linkage even though a function declaration defaults to external linkage if declared with none of `extern`, `static`, or `inline`. I'll edit my answer to add the `extern` keyword, although I have successfully compiled it with GCC even without the keyword.

Comment: @Danjiel See [C11 spec.
 section 6.7.4 para 10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4p10) for an example where an external definition of a function is created from an inline declaration.

Comment: @Danijel Note that if you want to call the externally linked `func1`, then exactly one of the compiled translation units being linked (in my example, the compiled output of "awesome_funcs.c") needs to define the `WANT_INLINE_FUNC1` macro, include "awesome_funcs.h", and have an external declaration of `func1`. That external declaration will be converted into an external definition copied from the inline declaration. But as I mentioned in an earlier comment, this may *really really* need the `extern` keyword which I missed out of my code earlier.

Comment: @Danijel [C11 spec. section 6.7.4 para 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4p7) does say that the `extern` keyword is required, so my original code without the `extern` was wrong. Perhaps the version of GCC I was using was being lenient.

Answer (score 1):

Declare/define the `inline` version and declare the non-`inline` version in the header file *with different names*.

```
// "func.h"

// normal
int func1(void);
int func2(void);
// inline versions
static inline int func1_inline(void) { ... }
static inline int func2_inline(void) { ... }
```

This allows a user to use either form or both.  There is little compelling reason to use the same name and only allow one form.

Both can be handy for code that needs speed vs. space on some calls and not others.

---

This has a benefit that the one .c file that defines/implements `func1(), func2()` can use simple code to insure equivalent functionality.

```
#include "func.h"

int func1(void) {
  return func1_inline();
}

int func2(void) {
  return func2_inline();
}
```

---

BTW, *declaring* a function like `int func1();` does not mean the same as `int func1(void);`.  `int func1();` means `func1` returns an `int`, but provids no information about what can be passed to it.  It is more like pseudo-code `int func1(...);`

Comment: Does this mean that I have duplicate (function definition) code in .h and .c, once for inlined and once for ext linked version?

Comment: @Danijel The .h file only is sufficient if in the.c file, code uses `int func1(void) {
  return func1_inline();
}`

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to add inline versions?

Your easiest course of action would be to declare `static` inline versions of these functions:

```
static inline int func1() { ... }
static inline int func3() { ... }
```

The function names do not need to differ from those of the corresponding external functions.  However, if you `#include` a header that has declarations of functions with those names, then they must be compatible, AND there must be prior `static` declarations.  For example:

```
static inline int func1(/* params */);
static inline int func3(/* params */);

#include "our_functions.h"

// ...

static inline int func1(/* params */) {
    // implementation ...
}

static inline int func3(/* params */) {
    // implementation ...
}
```

This will allow you to add inline versions without modifying your existing code that calls the external versions of these functions, and without affecting any other translation units.  There is at least one alternative, but I don't see anything to recommend it over the above for your particular circumstances.

Comment: Where do I "declare static inline versions of these functions"?

Comment: @Danijel, you declare them in the translation unit where they are to be used.  Nothing else needs to change.  The static versions will not be visible elsewhere.

Comment: That's fine, except when you want to inline the function calls from more than one translation unit.